# How to find and check obects with all properties being empty in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, object, oop, properties

For example, I create a `student` with all properties being empty

```
classdef student < handle

    properties
        name
        test
    end

    methods


        function obj = student(name)
            if nargin==1
            obj.name = name;
            obj.test = test();
            end
        end
    end
end
```

```
>> A=student

A = 

  student with properties:

    name: []
    test: []

>> isempty(A)

ans =

  logical

   0
```

But the output of `isempty(A)` is false. So what function can check if all properties of an object are empty? And How to find that kind of objects in a database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not many more choices than to loop through the properties of your object to check if they are all empty or not:

```
function isE = check_emptyness(A)

    props = properties(A);
    isE = true;

    for iprop = 1:length(props)
      
        if ~isempty(A.(props{iprop}))
    
            isE = false;
            break
    
        end    
    end
end
```

---

```
student_arr=[student('A') student()];
```

---

```
check_emptyness(student_arr(1))
```

> ans =
>
> logical
>
> 0

```
check_emptyness(student_arr(2))
```

> ans =
>
> logical
>
> 1

Comment: Thank you！I think your methods is very clever.

Answer (score 3):

You can overload the `isempty` method for your class:

```matlab
classdef student < handle

    properties
        name
        test
    end

    methods
        function obj = student(name)
            if nargin==1
               obj.name = name;
               obj.test = test();
            end
        end

        function res = isempty(obj)
            res = isempty(obj.name) && isempty(obj.test);
        end
    end
end
```

Now:

```matlab
>> A = student;
>> isempty(A)

ans =

  logical

   1
```

To find empty objects in a database, iterate over the elements in the database and check if they're empty.